# Cascading eslint config file

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have few questions about cascading eslint config file:

1. Can I use eslint like a `tsconfig.json` (in typescript) where I have a root `.eslintrc.yml` and I can extend/cascade that to each `.eslintrc.yml` for each folder (project)? I'm not sure if this is what the documentation says [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy).
2. If I can extend a root config file how does it work on the case of `extends` option where sometimes the order is important like on the case of `eslint-config-prettier` as mentioned on their [docs](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/master/README.md#installation). There it says:

> *Make sure to put it **last**, so it gets the chance to override other configs.*

4. Correct me if my understanding is correct that with `plugins` option the order is not important but on `extends` sometimes the order is important like what I mentioned on question #2.
5. If the order is important on `extends` option, how can I make sure that it follows the order when I have an extension like [`eslint-plugin-prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier) where it should be the last when I'm not using cascading. For example:

If I'm not using cascading it should be like this as what is mentioned [here](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier/blob/master/README.md#installation):

```
extends:
  - "some-other-config-you-use"
  - "prettier"
  - "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
  - "prettier/react"
```

If I'm using cascading my setup will be like this:

```
# root

root: true
parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
extends:
  - "eslint:recommended"
  - "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  - "prettier"
  - "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
```

```
# sub-folder

env:
  browser: true
extends: 
  - "plugins:react/recommended"
  - "plugins:jsx-a11y/recommended"
  - "prettier/react"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
root: true
parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser"
extends:
  - "eslint:recommended"
  - "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  - “./path/your_other_config”
  - "prettier"
  - "prettier/@typescript-eslint"
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to this, I was running into an error after creating the `.eslintrc.js` file in a subdirectory:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config
```

The solution was to specify `ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],` in the root config, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64975897/4139760).