# Parsing error "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, eslint, nestjs, prettier

I created a new [NestJS project](https://docs.nestjs.com/) which is a very popular NodeJS framework. But I have this error (see title) on my IDE (PhpStorm 2020.2-Beta) and ESLint doesn't work at all.

I've used the NestJS CLI :

```
nest new nestjs-micro
```

I don't seem to be the only one with this problem, so it would be nice to find the cause of this problem and **fix it once and for all.**

I already have an open [issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2303) but I haven't had an answer, this is really very problematic.

If anyone has an idea on how to fix the problem and **keeping an ESLint / Prettier integration with PhpStorm**, thanks.

**Repro**

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
  },
};
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

**Additional Info**
[image: Screenshot_20200716_233543]

**Versions**

```
Typescript: 3.7.4
Node: 14.3.0
ESLint: 7.1.0
@typescript-eslint/parser: 3.0.2
Yarn: 1.22.4
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out.

The error occurs when Typescript does not have a file to include for compilation.

The simplest solution is to create a **tsconfig.build.json** file for example and specify the following parameters in it :

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "dist/**/*spec.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*", ".eslintrc.js"]
}
```

The above example is adapted for NestJS but should work for other projects.

The most surprising thing is that it's only an error that shows up on PHPStorm, the build, it works fine.

Answer (score 13):

FWIW what worked for me with this error was to add `ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],` to the `.eslintrc.js` file. This line tells `eslint` to ignore the `.eslintrc.js` file (since it's not included in the `tsconfig` declared project `rootDir`).

Comment: This was also the solution to allow cascading eslintrc files, so that I can adjust linting rules in one subdirectory while still inheriting rules from the root config.

Comment: In my case I lint `js`, `cjs` and `ts`/`tsx` with the same eslint command and use override rules for several subsets of the checked files. I needed to add an `overrides` which disables rules requiring type config for all `*.cjs` and `*.js` files:
`overrides: [{ files: ['*.js', '*.cjs'], rules: { '@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises': 'off' }}]`

Answer (score 4):

Add it to the includes in tsconfig.json:

```
"include": [
  ".eslintrc.js",
]
```

Comment: I needed to add `env: {
  browser: true,
  es6: true,
  jest: true,
  node: true,
 },` to .eslintrc.js after doing that.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was due to `typings.d.ts` file and adding it t0 the includes in tsconfig.json:

```
"include": [
  ...
  "typings.d.ts",
  ...
]
```

resolved my issue.